# failing freeing dynamic struct array in c

Tags: c, struct, dynamic, free, allocation

I'm having some problem with freeing dynamic struct array and I can't understand why.

first of all there is this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[LEN];
    char address[MAX];         
} Airport;
```

And the constructor I made for this struct isn't using allocation for this struct building.

sec of all there is this struct:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        Airport* airports;
        int maxAPS;
        int currentAPS;
    } AirportManager;
//constructor
    void addAirport(AirportManager* pAirportManager)
    {
        if (pAirportManager->maxAPS == pAirportManager->currentAPS)
        {
            pAirportManager->maxAPS++;
            pAirportManager->airports = (Airport*)realloc(pAirportManager->airports, sizeof(Airport)*pAirportManager->maxAPS);
            //pAirportManager->airports[pAirportManager->currentAPS] = *(Airport*)malloc(sizeof(Airport)); 
        }....
```

and when I'm ending my program and want to free the AirportManager with the following code:

```
void freeAirportManager(AirportManager* pAirportManager)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pAirportManager->currentAPS; i++)
        free(&pAirportManager->airports[i]);
    free(pAirportManager->airports);
}
```

I've debuged this one and all the parameters are just fine but after one run in the loop the program exits, what should I change in the free function ?

do I need the marked line in the constructor ? I just added this on thinking it might help, but seems to not work as well... do I need to free only the array itself ?

Comment: From what little you show one possible explanation is that `pAirportManager` wasn't properly initialized.

Comment: Please work on a [mcve] so we can see the full picture.

Comment: `airports` is not an array of pointers, you don't need to free each element.

Comment: Get rid of the `for` loop.

Comment: but why I don't need to free every cell? I've added the constructor.

Comment: without a [mre] one can only guess, but you should be allocating space for `Airport* airports;` with something like `pAirportManager->airports = malloc(pAirportManager->maxAPS * sizeof(Airport));` Assuming that succeeds, each `airport[i]` points to an `Airport` object. You don't pass an object to `free`, you pass a pointer to the allocated memory for the objects. It doesn't matter if `pAirportManager->maxAPS` is 1 or 100, to clean up you call `free(pAirportManager->airports);`. In general, you should have the same number of `malloc` and `free` calls, where the `free`s "unwind" the `malloc`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pAirportManager->currentAPS; i++)
        free(&pAirportManager->airports[i]);
```

You need only to free `pAirportManager->airports`. You do not have pointer to pointer here.

So instead of those two lines:

```
free(pAirportManager->airports);
```

I would use flexible array member instead of pointer.

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[LEN];
    char address[MAX];         
} Airport;

typedef struct
{
    size_t maxAPS;
    size_t currentAPS;
    Airport airports[];
} AirportManager;
```

For sizes use `size_t` type instead of `int`